# Finding matching records from two tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables book1 and book2. I have `issue_date`column in both the tables. I want to get the records from both tables for matching issue date.

book1 and book2 have the following columns -

```
book_id | user_id | numofbooks | issue_date
```

I tried this SQL query given below but doesn't work -

```
SELECT * FROM `book1`, `book2` WHERE issue_date between '2014-04-06' and '2014-05-07';
```

Throws an error. Is it possible to do it SQL way or should i query both the tables separately and merge the result sets?

Comment: You should edit your question with sample data and your desired results.

Comment: Why do you have 2 tables with the same type of data? You should normalize the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM book1
WHERE issue_date between '2014-04-06' and '2014-05-07'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM book2
WHERE issue_date between '2014-04-06' and '2014-05-07';
```

This will only work if book1 and book2 have the same columns in the same order, in which case it's questionable why this wasn't designed as 1 table in the first place.

If the columns don't match exactly you can replace `*` with the relevant column names.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that you really want a cartesian product of all matching records from the two tables.

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM book1
WHERE issue_date between '2014-04-06' and '2014-05-07'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM book2
WHERE issue_date between '2014-04-06' and '2014-05-07';
```

This assumes that the two tables have exactly the same columns defined in the same order (and that, in turn, would suggest a bad database design). In practice, you would replace the `*` with the columns you really want.

Answer (score 2):

you can **apply Union All** feature as mentioned above but you should have the **same name of the fields** in both the tables book1 & book2